# Retrieve data returned by a Stored Procedure: Php & MS SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

> This question relates to:
>
> PHP Version 5.3.6
>
> [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170(v=sql.90).aspx)

I am trying to properly retrieve data from a stored procedure.

This question assumes the existence of the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure
AS
     BEGIN
           SET NOCOUNT ON
           --A bunch of SQL statements
           --More SQL statements
           SELECT 'Doctor Who Rules!'
     END
```

I've tried the following code which runs through all of my commands but does not return the data from the final SELECT.

```
$sql = "EXEC test_procedure;";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
$next_result = sqlsrv_next_result($result); // returns a boolean
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
```

Using sqlsrv_execute does not work with the above code either.

How can I return the data geneated by the stored procedure above via PHP?

Thank you.

**Addendum #1 (Classic ASP Counterpart)**

```
sqlCMD = "EXEC test_procedure;"
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open _ConnectionString_Variable_
Set rs = conn.Execute(sqlCMD)
```

I would get back a recordset with one row that has one field with the data "Doctor Who Rules!"

Comment: You'd need to specify an output parameter in the procedure - right now you've only got a single input (@foo). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx  (see 'out' and 'output').

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I’m not sure your comment is relevant to my question. Let me clarify. The issue at hand is that I should be getting back the final SELECT in the stored procedure, but I am not. I have edited the question so that the SELECT statement in the stored procedure so that it is clearer and not dependent on the input. The question remains the same.

Comment: It may seem not relevant, but please provide the `users` table definition. I had similar issue recenty, but I won't be sure about the answer unless I see the table.

Comment: I think I may have been too granular with my example. I have removed elements that are not relevant to my question (e.g, I have removed the input variable @foo and changed the SQL statement to something that does not rquire a table). I have also added a snippet of classic ASP code which behaves in the manner I would like the PHP to behave.

Comment: Table definition, please. What types of columns do you have there?

Comment: @jacek , There is no table in my example.

Comment: And still no effect? My problem came from using the `nvarchar` type and the DB driver had problems with the unicode transfer to the PHP. Changing the type to `varchar` helped. Changing the driver helped as well, but can't tell you to which one - my DB admin did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

The PHP code in my example will work properly if `SET NOCOUNT ON` is ommited from the Stored Procedure. With `SET NOCOUNT ON` in the procedure, there is no data stream back to PHP and thus, the results of the last `SELECT` never makes it back.

Therfore, this Stored procedure...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure
     @foo varchar(25)
AS
     BEGIN
          --A bunch of SQL statements
          --More SQL statements
          SELECT @foo
END
```

...will work perfectly with this PHP...

```
$sql = "EXEC test_procedure 'Dr. Who Rules!';";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
$next_result = sqlsrv_next_result($result);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
```

You will end up with a recordset with the string "Doctor Who Rules!"

Answer (score 1):

I just hit the same problem a few minutes ago, and this thread pointed me towards a working solution (I'm not sure that it is a "right"solution, but it works).

Actually, the problem was not being caused by "SET NOCOUNT ON". In my case, it was a couple of PRINT statements that were left there after debugging.

Looks like any output from the SP other than the actual recordset, causes the problem.